# Fields missing on an Index of Elasticsearch from one moment to another

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-schema

A strange situation happened with the elasticsearch i use to log things.
I'm using Nlog with a target elasticsearch that conforms with ECS (elastic common schema)

https://github.com/elastic/ecs-dotnet/tree/master/src/Elastic.CommonSchema.NLog

By some reason since today, some fields went missing, one of them is the very important field `message`.

Looking the logs of the stream of `kibana` inside the `Observability` menu i see the following:

[image]

We can see here that the message field simple disappeared. Can something provoke this? If yes, what steps can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something wrong on the logs,

In the advanced options, for the template, i added an include field.

This was only letting that specific field being logged.